# Reasoning over OWL cardinality restriction

Tags: owl, semantic-web, protege, hermit

I think I still have a fundamental misunderstanding of OWL axioms :(.

Here is a small test ontology I created:

```
@prefix xsd:      <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdf:      <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix rdfs:     <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix owl:      <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix :         <http://foobar.com/test/> .

: a owl:Ontology .

:prop1 a owl:DatatypeProperty .
:prop2 a owl:DatatypeProperty .

:Class1 owl:equivalentClass [
    a owl:Restriction ;
    owl:onProperty :prop1 ;
    owl:cardinality "1"^^xsd:int
  ] .

:Ind1 a owl:NamedIndividual ;
  :prop1 "value1"^^xsd:string .

:Class2 owl:equivalentClass [
    a owl:Restriction ;
    owl:onProperty :prop2 ;
    owl:minCardinality "1"^^xsd:int
  ] .

:Ind2 a owl:NamedIndividual ;
  :prop2 "value2"^^xsd:string .
```

When I run the Hermit reasoner in Protege over this, I get the expected result with `:Ind2`, that is it is a member of `:Class2`. But I am not getting the same for `:Ind1` with regards to being a member of `:Class1`.

I am suspecting that this has to do with open world assumption and that it is possible that `:Ind1` might still have another `:prop1` assertion. So couple of questions:

- Have I diagnosed the problem correctly?
- Can I get an example of how I can get my goal for hermit to reason that `:Ind1` is a member of `:Class1` without explicitly making the assertion?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Premise

OWL semantics is defined under [open-world assumption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-world_assumption), so you can't check if the cardinality for a certain property is *exactly* N, because there may be other property instances even if not declared.

More precisely, these are the checks that you can do:

| Cardinality check | Possible answers | Sound | Complete |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| At-least N | **Yes** (if N or more) I don't know (otherwise) | Yes | No |
| Exactly N | **No** (if N+1 or more) I don't know (otherwise) | Yes | No |
| At-most N | **No** (if N+1 or more) I don't know (otherwise) | Yes | No |

#### Solution

You can check if a cardinality is *exactly* 1 only if you **explicitly** state that `"value1"` is the only value for `:Ind1`. In this case `:Ind1` will be part of `:Class1`.

In FOL:

> ∀x.(R(Ind1, x) → x = "value1")

In DL:

> ∃R⁻.{Ind1} ⊑ {"value1"}

In OWL2 (not tested):

```
:Ind1
  a owl:NamedIndividual ;
  a [ a                 owl:Restriction ;
      owl:onProperty    :prop1 ;
      owl:allValuesFrom [ a          rdfs:Datatype ;
                          owl:oneOf  ( "value1"^^xsd:string )
                        ]
    ] .
```

Comment: Please take a look at my comment below as that seems to do the trick without needing to declare individual restrictions.

Comment: @stan_plogic For some reason I took for granted that you were searching for an extensional solution. If you can modify your intensional axioms, that solution is clearly better.

Comment: I am still admiring your solution. Glad to hear there is a name for it...:) If you could add both the solutions to your answer, I will delete my comment below and accept your answer again. I can edit it, but it seems to put that on a review list as I am still a newbie on this platform.

Comment: @stan_plogic To me, it is ok like this  ;-) Anyway I realized the reason why I din't suggest you the FunctionalProperty solution. Basically I thought you were searching for a general solution for any kind of "minCardinality"/"cardinality" and you wanted to understand the main difference between them.

Comment: Fair enough. I will accept your answer, if for nothing else making me read on intensional vs extensional definitions :). Thanks for taking the time. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @horcrux for providing the hint. What worked finally is to also declare the properties as `owl:FunctionalProperty`. Editing the property declarations to:

```
:prop1 a owl:DatatypeProperty, owl:FunctionalProperty .
:prop2 a owl:DatatypeProperty, owl:FunctionalProperty .
```

This does not require adding additional restrictions to each individual declaration.